# HTTP tunnel proxy solutions to escape corporate proxy & firewall

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall

I have a system in a corporate network with a very restrive firewall:

- **no SSH**
- only direct traffic allowed is to the corporate HTTP proxy server (80/443)
- Deep Packet Inspection

I would like to setup a program in between my system and the corporate proxy, that would encapsulate my browser requests to look like they are going to an allowed host under my control on the internet.

This host would deencapsulate the real HTTP request, and act as a proxy. It would encapsulate the response and relay it back to the corporate proxy, that would relay it back to my program, that would deencapsulate it for the browser consumption.

I have made a drawing of the current situation, and one of the setup I'm thinking of.

My question is, are there software already implementing this pair of programs?
I think it is starting to look like a 1-level Tor network...

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for advice for bypassing a company's security.

Comment: You need to discuss this with the company's IT people. We can't give such advice.